# Merge two data tables but avoid duplicate columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two data tables, `dat` and `dat2`. There are a few columns that appear in both tables, though the values are not necessarily the same in each.

When I merge the two tables using `dat[dat2]` everything works as expected, except that I have some duplicate column names. For instance, a column named `Status` appears in both tables and, when merged, the column from `dat2` appears as `i.Status`. Rather than renaming these columns, I simply want to drop them from the table altogether. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You can drop them after the merge or you can subset during the merge.

Comment: Simplest way is to provide columns which you want to keep from join to `j` argument.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid manually typing out all of the column names. I can drop columns that start with `i.` after the merge, but that's a hack

Answer (score 2):

Below is some code to illustrate methods for the two scenarios I mentioned, though there may be some fancier (more efficient) `data.table` (version 1.9.6) methods.

Both methods will dynamically adapt to the variable overlap, so you don't have to worry about manually typing out the names.

```
# get some data
set.seed(1234)
dt <- data.table(id=1:10, a=letters[1:10], b=rnorm(10), d=rnorm(10))
dt2 <- data.table(id=1:10, a=letters[5:14], c=rnorm(10), d=rnorm(10))
```

Here's the data without dropping:

```
dt[dt2, on="id"]

    id a          b           d i.a          c        i.d
 1:  1 a -1.2070657 -0.47719270   e  0.1340882  1.1022975
 2:  2 b  0.2774292 -0.99838644   f -0.4906859 -0.4755931
 3:  3 c  1.0844412 -0.77625389   g -0.4405479 -0.7094400
 4:  4 d -2.3456977  0.06445882   h  0.4595894 -0.5012581
 5:  5 e  0.4291247  0.95949406   i -0.6937202 -1.6290935
 6:  6 f  0.5060559 -0.11028549   j -1.4482049 -1.1676193
 7:  7 g -0.5747400 -0.51100951   k  0.5747557 -2.1800396
 8:  8 h -0.5466319 -0.91119542   l -1.0236557 -1.3409932
 9:  9 i -0.5644520 -0.83717168   m -0.0151383 -0.2942939
10: 10 j -0.8900378  2.41583518   n -0.9359486 -0.4658975
```

*method 1*: subset during the merge / join using the `intersect` and `mget` functions.

```
# assuming your id variable is the first column in both sets:
dropVars <- intersect(names(dt), names(dt2))[-1]

dt[dt2[, mget(names(dt2)[-which(names(dt2) %in% dropVars)])], on="id"]
```

*method 2*: drop after merge using `grep`

```
dt3 <- dt[dt2, on="id"]
dt3[, grep("^i\\.", names(dt3), value=TRUE) := NULL]
```

Both of these methods return

```
    id a          b           d          c
 1:  1 a -1.2070657 -0.47719270  0.1340882
 2:  2 b  0.2774292 -0.99838644 -0.4906859
 3:  3 c  1.0844412 -0.77625389 -0.4405479
 4:  4 d -2.3456977  0.06445882  0.4595894
 5:  5 e  0.4291247  0.95949406 -0.6937202
 6:  6 f  0.5060559 -0.11028549 -1.4482049
 7:  7 g -0.5747400 -0.51100951  0.5747557
 8:  8 h -0.5466319 -0.91119542 -1.0236557
 9:  9 i -0.5644520 -0.83717168 -0.0151383
10: 10 j -0.8900378  2.41583518 -0.9359486
```

Comment: or `keep <- union(names(dt), names(dt2)) ; dt[dt2, mget(keep), on = "id"]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg That's better, it avoids the irritating `-which()` syntax.